# How to display contact information in footer template Open Cart?

Tags: opencart, opencart-3

I use new version of OpenCart 3.
In administrativ part I can set default phone/email data.
Then in `footer.twig` I tried to display phone number like:

```
{{  config.get('config_phone') }}
```

Comment: you need to pass the number from controller in a variable. Check catalog/controller/common/footer.php and then use the variable in your footer.twig

Comment: Do you mean to assign global variable in controller and then I can to get access to it in view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In catalog/controller/common/footer.php

```
$data['telephone_number'] = $this->config->get('config_telephone');
```

In catalog/view/theme/default/template/common/footer.twig

```
{{ telephone_number }}
```